# Why are rubber sheet deformations continuous?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, continuity, fundamental-groups

In topology,we are often told that homeomorphism can be thought of as a continuous deformation of a shape. I mean by continuous deformation the actions of twisting, bending, stretching but not tearing or gluing.

My question is how can I show formally that these actions satisfy the definitions of homeomorphism. Suppose we are asked to check a continuous surjection from a shape to another. Does it suffice if I could achieve the second from the first by twisting, stretching and bending and not tearing. Even we are allowed to glue (identify two points) here, because we are required to check continuous surjection, so injectivity may be violated. But I want to make it clear to me that these vague actions actually are continuous as maps. How can I show that.

Comment: "How can I show formally that these actions satisfy the definition of homeomorphism?" These actions would first need to be defined precisely, which they have not been. Twisting, bending, and stretching are just informal visual descriptions of the types of transformations we're trying to describe when we define a homeomorphism. If someone gave a precise definition of "bending" then you could prove bending is a homeomorphism, but I think this is never done.

Comment: @littleO actually I have been looking for that formal and precise meaning of those terms.

Comment: The point is that such a definition does not exist. A "bending" is whatever looks like bending something; you know it when you see it. Those are just informal terms, they don't have a definition.